# Autologin & RDP

Tags: 20.04, remote-desktop, xrdp, rdp, auto-login

First, apologies if my question was asked many times before or the answer is super obvious to you. I spend 2 hours or so searching for an answer and tried numerous things. I even asked ChatGPT (sounded good, but was leading nowhere).

Here my problem resp setup:

Host: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Client: Windows 11

Overall everything works. RDP works, too.

BUT: As soon as I change the setting in Ubuntu to **autologin**, the RDP login doesn't work anymore. If I disable autologin in Ubuntu, all works again.

What I would like is either to be logged in with RDP into the already running session or starting a "second session" independently from the already running one.

How to achieve this?

Comment: XRDP in Linux don't work like RDP in Windows. It won't work if you are logged in locally. It only works if you are not logged in.